# LINQ Optimizations for IOrderedEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, optimization

Is anyone aware of whether there are there any built-in capabilities in the LINQ library (or a publicly available utility library) for optimized operations on `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, as opposed to `IEnumerable<T>`?

For example, in theory, the `Contains<T>()` extension could potentially be optimized to use binary search when it is applied to a finite `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and T is IComparable.

Another example, would be an optimized version of `Distinct<T>()` that would be deferred and streamable (since on an ordered, comparable collection you can always use skip/match techniques to produce a distinct set).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are problems there...

- A binary search can't be executed on an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, as it ideally needs indexer access into a list/array. So it would have to call something like `ToList()`/`ToArray()` first
- `Distinct` works on the `T` items, but `OrderBy` works on some *facet* of each `T` - it isn't quite the same, unless you happen to know that it is ordered by `item=>item`; which is rarely the case (and hard to prove).

Comment: Excellent points ... I didn't consider implications of what ordering a collection could mean in all cases.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't need to know that it's ordered by item=>item, as long as you know that the IEqualityComparer passed to Distinct obeys the same ordering as that used by OrderBy. As you say, though, you can't know this in all cases. I guess you could capture the IComparer used by OrderBy/ThenBy, and use that, but it's likely way too much work.